# Does packing everything into resources still affect scene loading time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've had a serious problem with loading times on low-end devices. One of my testers reported that launching the game takes up to a minute, and no other game takes that long.

I decided to 'fix' this by putting every single asset into Resources and making a LoadingScreen scene. It's almost entirely empty - one text field and 16 images representing a part loading at that specific moment, as well as one script called LoadingScreen.cs, which preloads everything into memory. Here it is:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using TMPro;

public class LoadingScreen : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject[] steps;
    public GameObject text;
    public GameObject theCamera;
    public GameObject loaderObjects;

    Object[] textures;
    Object[] sprites;
    Object[] models;
    Object[] materials;
    Object[] audios;
    Object[] animations;
    Object[] shaders;
    Object[] fonts;
    Object[] scripts;

    void Start() {
        Physics.autoSimulation = false;

        StartCoroutine (Initialization ());
    }

    IEnumerator Initialization() {

        text.GetComponent<TMP_Text> ().text = "INITIALIZATION";

        GameObject MainCameraPrefab = Resources.Load("Prefabs/Main Camera") as GameObject;
        theCamera = Instantiate (MainCameraPrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.Euler (Vector3.zero));

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        StartCoroutine (LoadScenes ());
    }

    IEnumerator LoadScenes() {
        steps[0].gameObject.SetActive(true);

        text.GetComponent<TMP_Text> ().text = "LOADING SCENES";

        theCamera.GetComponent<LevelChanger> ().StartLoadingLevels ();

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        StartCoroutine (LoadTextures ());
    }

    IEnumerator LoadTextures() {
        steps[1].gameObject.SetActive(true);

        text.GetComponent<TMP_Text> ().text = "LOADING TEXTURES & SPRITES";

        textures = Resources.LoadAll("Models/Textures", typeof(Texture2D));
        sprites = Resources.LoadAll("Sprites", typeof(Texture2D));

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        StartCoroutine (LoadMeshes ());
    }

    IEnumerator LoadMeshes() {
        steps[2].gameObject.SetActive(true);

        text.GetComponent<TMP_Text> ().text = "LOADING MESHES & MATERIALS";

        materials = Resources.LoadAll("Models/Materials", typeof(Material));
        models = Resources.LoadAll("Models", typeof(Mesh));

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        StartCoroutine (LoadAudio ());
    }

    IEnumerator LoadAudio() {
        steps[3].gameObject.SetActive(true);

        text.GetComponent<TMP_Text> ().text = "LOADING AUDIO";

        audios = Resources.LoadAll("Sounds", typeof(AudioClip));

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        StartCoroutine (LoadAssets ());
    }

    IEnumerator LoadAssets() {
        steps[4].gameObject.SetActive(true);

        text.GetComponent<TMP_Text> ().text = "LOADING OTHER ASSETS";

        animations = Resources.LoadAll("Animations");
        shaders = Resources.LoadAll("Shaders");
        fonts = Resources.LoadAll("Fonts");

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        StartCoroutine (LoadScripts ());
    }

    IEnumerator LoadScripts() {
        steps[5].gameObject.SetActive(true);

        text.GetComponent<TMP_Text> ().text = "LOADING SCRIPTS";

        scripts = Resources.LoadAll("Scripts");

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        StartCoroutine (InitializeScripts ());
    }

    IEnumerator InitializeScripts() {
        steps[6].gameObject.SetActive(true);

        text.GetComponent<TMP_Text> ().text = "INITIALIZING SCRIPTS";

        theCamera.GetComponent<SaveGame> ().enabled = true;
        theCamera.GetComponent<SteamManager> ().enabled = true;
        theCamera.GetComponent<CameraControl> ().enabled = true;
        theCamera.GetComponent<FPSCounter> ().enabled = true;
        theCamera.GetComponent<TimerCounter> ().enabled = true;
        theCamera.GetComponent<TimeManager> ().enabled = true;
        theCamera.GetComponent<BlurControl> ().enabled = true;
        theCamera.GetComponent<Pause> ().enabled = true;
        theCamera.GetComponent<SkyboxRotation> ().enabled = true;
        theCamera.GetComponent<SoundManager> ().enabled = true;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        StartCoroutine (Done ());
    }

    IEnumerator Done() {
        steps[7].gameObject.SetActive(true);

        text.GetComponent<TMP_Text> ().text = "DONE";

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.4f);

        theCamera.GetComponent<LevelChanger> ().ActivateMenu ();
        Destroy (loaderObjects);
    }
}
```

The scene looks like this:

[image]

Well, I know that is not a common approach but it works specifically for me, since most levels just reuse the same prefabs, same models and same materials. Preloading everything is just a few extra hundreds of megabytes of memory used but it speeds up scene loading times a whole lot!

Well, it did, indeed, speed up loading of different scenes and it removed the first hiccup when placing some prefab for the first time. Good. But it did not help me with initial loading times, not at all, still takes a lot of time to launch the game. I checked dependencies of the scene:

[image]

One sprite - that part of the circle, a few TextMeshPro related assets, one shader and two scripts - the one I mentioned above and the one preventing my preloaded objects from getting destroyed on changing the scene (it's just one line, should not matter either).

I've read before that Resources are not loaded into the memory until the moment I decide to use them. So what might be the issue here? Why does it take Unity so long to launch an empty scene?

Comment: I would check using asset bundles. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html

Comment: Good advice, I've read it's an alternative but I'd preferably like to know what's wrong with one method before switching to another.